# Calculation of MACD using List in R

Tags: r

I have loaded the stock prices in to a list (DATA) in R. Say, DATA[[1]] is AAPL. If I have the following columns under each stock : Date, Open, High, Low , Close. The issue is when I calculate MACD and assign it to the a column in the list using :

```
DATA[[1]]$Macd <- MACD(DATA[[1]]$Close,nFast=12, nSlow=26, nSig=9, maType = "EMA")
```

I get a single column of values, which I am unsure of what values are those.

But when I calculate MACD by assigning it to a variable

```
 macd <- MACD(DATA[[2]]$Close,nFast=12, nSlow=26, nSig=9, maType = "EMA")
```

I  get two columns **macd** and **signal**.

Can someone help me figure out how I could get two columns values ( macd and signal) when I use the MACD function to calculate values in a List ?

P.S. I have used the **MACD** function under **TTR** package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already figured out, the MACD function provides two columns of values - **macd** and **signal**.
All you need to do is assign them to not one but two new columns in DATA[[1]] by referencing their MACD indexes - 1 and 2.
Here is the code:

```
library(quantmod)
DATA <- list(getSymbols('AAPL', from=Sys.Date()-100, auto.assign=FALSE))
names(DATA[[1]])=c('open','high','low','close','volume','adjusted')
macd <- MACD(DATA[[1]]$close, maType='EMA')
   tail(macd, 2)  #verify
DATA[[1]]$macd <- macd[,1]
DATA[[1]]$sgnl <- macd[,2]
   tail(DATA[[1]][,c('macd','sgnl')], 2)  #verify
```

P.S.  since you are using MACD default values (nFast = 12, nSlow = 26, nSig = 9), you can omit them in the code.